# npm rebuild, electron-rebuild doesn't use special parameters

Tags: npm, electron, npm-scripts, better-sqlite3, electron-rebuild

I have an electron/React app running. So after I install all packages I have to execute `electron-rebuild` so there are no version issues.

I install one package in the `preinstall` script: `npm install better-sqlite3  --build-from-source --sqlite3=my sqlite amalgamation folder`

Now the problem is that `electron-rebuild/npm rebuild` just installs better-sqlite3 and not better-sqlite3 with my customized amalgamation.

This makes it unusable for me because I need my customized version of sqlite.

Does anyone know how to solve this, how to make electron-rebuild/npm rebuild install that package with the extra parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I created a library to fix this issue/get around it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3-sqleet.

So the problem is solved for me, but it would be nice to still have an answer on the original question.